# dynamically crop images with imagemagick

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, imagemagick

So I have some erb that dynamically generates step-by-step instructions based on a users input. In each step there is text and then at least one image with an image tag overlaid on top (highlights what the step instruction text is referring to). The problem is right now the image dimensions are too big to be conducive for displaying on mobile. (Their max width is 640px). I have the X-Y position of each tag so I want to dynamically crop around each tag to reduce their width when the instructions load (I think 300px would be fine). I was wondering how I would do this with imagemagick? Or is there a better way to go about this? Thanks in advance!

ERB (how each step is generated)

```
<% n = steps.index(step) %>
<section id="step<%= n+1 %>" style="padding-top: 60px;">
<h2 style="margin-left:20px;"> Step <%= n+1 %></h2>
<div class="stepcontainer">
    <div class="steptext">
        <% if step.priority == 1 %>
            <%= "Plug the #{step.i_connection.cord_type.name} end of the cable into the #{step.i_product.full_name}.  Then plug the #{step.o_connection.cord_type.name} end into the #{step.o_product.full_name}." %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 2 %>
            <%= "Plug the #{step.i_connection.cord_type.name} end of the cable into the #{step.i_product.full_name}.  Then plug the #{step.o_connection.cord_type.name} end into the #{step.o_product.full_name}." %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 3 %>
            <%= "Plug the #{step.o_connection.product.full_name } #{step.o_connection.cord_type.name} Cable into the wall." %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 4 %>
            <%= "Plug the #{step.i_connection.cord_type.name} end of the cable into the #{step.i_connection.product.full_name}.  Then plug the #{step.o_connection.cord_type.name} end into the #{step.o_connection.product.full_name}." %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 5 %>
            <%= "Plug #{step.o_connection.product.full_name}" %>
        <% elsif step.priority == 6 %>
            <%= "Touch the #{step.o_connection.button.name} Button on the #{step.o_connection.product.full_name}" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="modalbutton">
        <%= render(step.flags.new) %>   
    </div>

    <div class="productimg">    
        <span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>

    <% if step.input_contact.present? %>
        <span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.i_connection.pos_height %>" ="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>    

        <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:300px; position:relative;">
            <%= link_to image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:medium)), "#{step.i_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
            <div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="cableimg">
        <% if step.i_connection.cord_type.present? %>
            <%= image_tag(step.i_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "orange")  %>
        <% end %>           
        <% end %>   

        <% if step.o_connection.cord_type.present? %>
            <%= image_tag(step.o_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "green") %>      
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <% if step.o_connection.button.present? %>
        <div class="productimg">
            <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:300px; position:relative;">
                <%= link_to image_tag(step.o_connection.image.image.url(:medium)), "#{step.o_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
                <div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>

    <% else %>
        <div class="productimg">
            <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:300px; position:relative;">
                <%= link_to image_tag(step.o_connection.image.image.url(:medium)), "#{step.o_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
                <div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>              
    <% end %>
</div>
</section>
```

jQuery (how the tags are added)

```
$('span.i_contact').each(function() {                
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = ($(this).data('pos-x')) / 2.1;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) / 2.1;
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid orange",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos
    });

    var n = $(this).data('index')
    $('.i_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)  
    console.log(taggedNode.position())    
});

$("span.o_contact").each(function() {            
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = ($(this).data('pos-x')) / 2.1;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) / 2.1;

    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid green",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos  
    });
    var n = $(this).data('index')
    $('.o_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)        
});
```

Comment: Check out this RailCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images. Is this what you need?

Comment: That's more user end I think. I need something that will automatically crop the photo (say 20px) around the x & y coordinates when the instructions load

Comment: The example itself is more user end but you could probably implement it for your needs too with some tweaking